# How to select child element inside first, second or third html element with CSS classes?

Tags: html, css

I want to select anchor tags in CSS.For the purpose in the following html document I did the same.

My html document is here:

```
<div class="first">
   <center><a href="http://www.google.com">The first link </a></center>
</div>

<div class="second">
   <center><a href="http://www.fb.com">The second link</a></center>
</div>

<div class="third">
   <center><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">The third link</a></center>
</div>
```

Now I want to select all of a tags. I tried in this way:

```
body a:first-child:hover//The first child
{
    font-size:30px;
    color:yellow;
}
body a+a:hover  //the second child
{
    font-size:40px;
    color:red;
}
body a+a+a:hover  //the third child
{
    font-size:50px;
    color:#fff;
}
```

But I am getting wrong result what should I do?

Comment: why don't you use ids?

Comment: Sitenote: Do not use ``<center>`` because it is a [non comforming feature](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features) in HTML 5. Use ``div { text-align: center; }`` instead in your CSS

Comment: @Asenar I am writing my own code :)

Comment: Like most people here I think ;) and sorry I proposed a not-really-so-accurate title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `<a>` elements are not adjacent siblings (or siblings at all), so the adjacent sibling selector (`+`) doesn't apply to them.

The div elements are siblings.

```
body div:first-child a:hover//The first child
{
    font-size:30px;
    color:yellow;
}
body  div+div a:hover  //the second child
{
    font-size:40px;
    color:red;
}
body div+div+div a:hover  //the third child
{
    font-size:50px;
    color:#fff;
}
```

You aren't using, and don't need to use, classes for this.

Comment: Which one is the better solution?

Answer (score 4):

You can easily select like this :

```
.first a:first-child:hover//The first child
{
    font-size:30px;
    color:yellow;
}
.second a:nth-child(2):hover  //the second child
{
    font-size:40px;
    color:red;
}
.third a:nth-child(3):hover  //the third child
{
    font-size:50px;
    color:#fff;
}
```

For modern browsers, use `a:nth-child(2)` for the second a, and `a:nth-child(3)` for the third.

Hope this helped.

Comment: @jahan sorry, just mistake, i have edited the answer. check again.

Comment: I could not get "Remember that these retrieve the second and third td for every row."

Comment: The `a` elements in the markup are *all* the `:first-child`. Your `:nth-child` code won't work.

Comment: @Quentin of course the Css of question was not correct, will be fixed now, thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
.first{
font-size:30px;
color:yellow;
}
.first a:hover{
    font-size:40px;
    color:red;
}
 .second a:hover{
font-size:40px;
color:red;
}
.third a:hover{
    font-size:50px;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need any classes for this, you can just use the `:nth-child(n)`-selector for this (see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) for refrence.)

Also there is no need to use the body selector before (to declare that the body is a parent-element of the a). The body is the parent-element of every visible element of the page, so adding this into the selector hierarchy doesn't make much sense.

However if you want to use your already existing classes, you can do the following:

```
.first a:hover
{
    font-size:30px;
    color:yellow;
}    
.second a:hover
{
    font-size:40px;
    color:red;
}
.third a:hover
{
    font-size:50px;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: The `a` elements in the markup are *all* the `:first-child`. Your `:nth-child` code won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
body a {
//your rules here
}
```

This will select all anchor tags in your site.

Answer (score 0):

Just target the anchor directly:

```
a {
    color: pink;
}
```

To set the styles for hover and visited:

```
a:focus,
a:hover {
    color: green;
}

a:visited {
    color: blue;
}
```

---

Aside: it seems you need to learn basic CSS. I suggest "CSS Diner" at http://flukeout.github.io/ might be a good exercise.

Answer (score 0):

use association to your `div` `class` elements

```
.first a:hover//The first child
{
    font-size:30px;
    color:yellow;
}
.second a:hover  //the second child
{
    font-size:40px;
    color:red;
}
.third a:hover  //the third child
{
    font-size:50px;
    color:#fff;
}
```