# How to select one hr tag amidst many within a div tag without any class or id

Tags: html, css

So i have this sort of structure

```
<div class="about_page"> 
   <hr>
   <hr>
</div>
```

How do i select the second hr tag and style it in such a way that it wont affect the first.

Note that i dont have access to the Html of the code so i cant add any id or class selectors to the code. I also do not have access to write any javascript for the code. I want to use pure css

Comment: @PizzaBoy he said he can't add any classes?

Comment: @PizzaBoy the original question said "I don't have access to the HTML"?

Comment: just calm down, I've deleted my recommendation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select child element inside first, second or third html element with CSS classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22859812/how-to-select-child-element-inside-first-second-or-third-html-element-with-css)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the  [:nth-child() Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/sel_nth-child.asp).

In your case:

```
.about_page hr:nth-child(2) {

    /* your style here */

}
```

Comment: it fits the requirement only if you have nothing else than hr at the first positions inside the container , add some text in between and you loose it :(

Comment: @G-Cyr I know it, but the question seems to be related to this specific structure. Anyway... thanks for your clarification :)

Comment: okay, looks funny that a template would generate 2 hrs before including any content, looks too easy ;) . If the op did not know about this, maybe you could include a link to specifications or a tutorial about the nth-child pseudo rules ;)

Answer (score 1):

Via CSS you may take a look at selector [`~`*(difference with child and sibling selectors)*](https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/) and `initial` or `unset` values

https://www.quirksmode.org/css/cascading/values.html

> The `inherit`, `initial`, and `unset` keywords are special values you can give to any CSS property.

---

example below is changing the `border-color` value to the second hr encountered within a container , any content can stand in between first, second and other hr.

```css
hr:first-of-type~hr {/* reset css value after the first hr seen in the container */
  border-color: red;
}

hr:first-of-type~hr~hr {/* reset to older value any hr following the second hr from the container*/
  border-color: initial;
  /* or border-color:unset; */
}
```

```html
<div class="about_page">
  <hr>
  <div>something</div>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <p>some text</p>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <div>something</div>
  <hr>
</div>
works too with just hrs
<div class="about_page">
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
</div>
```